# Using Linq to find a group of common objects

Tags: c#, linq

What I'm trying to do is, if you look below in the code, write a Linq statement that will return the group of ShiftEvents.  A group is defined by 1.) EmpId, 2.) EndDate/Time of one ShiftEvent = StartDate/Time of the next ShiftEvent

I want to then create a Shift object where I put the group of ShiftEvents in Shift.List<ShiftEvents>.

I've got a half assed written Linq statement that does seem to join the ShiftEvents..it's the grouping portion I'm completely lost on.

```
class ShiftEvent{
    public int EmpId { get; set; }
    public string Activity { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
}

class Shift{
    public List<ShiftEvent> ShiftEvents { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartOfShiftDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartOfShiftTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndOfShiftDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndOfShiftTime { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    List<ShiftEvent> se = new List<ShiftEvent>();
    // Group 1
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/21", StartTime="23:00",EndDate="2015/01/21",EndTime="23:30"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/21", StartTime="23:30",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="00:30"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="00:30",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="05:30"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="05:30",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="06:30"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="06:30",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="07:00"});
    // Group 2
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="07:15",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="09:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="09:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="10:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="10:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="11:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="11:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="12:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=1, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="12:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="13:00"});
    // Group 3
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=2, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="07:15",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="09:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=2, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="09:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="10:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=2, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="10:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="11:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=2, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="11:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="12:00"});
    se.Add(new ShiftEvent {EmpId=2, Activity="Test", StartDate="2015/01/22", StartTime="12:00",EndDate="2015/01/22",EndTime="13:00"});


    var obj = from s1 in se
            join s2 in se
                on new {EmpId = s1.EmpId, Date = s1.EndDate, Time = s1.EndTime} equals new {EmpId = s2.EmpId, Date=s2.StartDate, Time = s2.StartTime}
            select s1;

    var shiftList = new List<Shift>();

    foreach(var shiftEvent in obj){
        var shift = new Shift();
        shift.ShiftEvent.Add(shiftEvent);
        shift.EmployeeId = shiftEvent.EmpId;
        .......
        shiftList.Add(shift);
    }


}
```

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: So what's the real issue.. you have not stated in your `half assed` solution works, almost works, or doesn't work at all..

Comment: The issue is I have no idea where to start in my Linq statement to get the Group of ShiftEvents.  In the sample code there are 3 groups. I don't know how to break that out from what I have now.

Comment: The code you have will pair up records within a group, but other than that it doesn't seem helpful. For example, for your group #1, I would expect you to still wind up with four records (i.e. all but the last, which has no record to pair with). You don't even take any value from `s2`, so you just wind up with a copy of `s1`. Instead, it seems to me you should forget the `join`, and instead `group by` on the employee #, `order by` the date/time, and then outside the LINQ expression, use e.g. `Aggregate()` to accumulate contiguous records into individual list objects.

Comment: You might want to correct the typo in your Shift class `StartOfShiftTime` field! :) And while you're at it, you should use properties instead of fields.

Comment: @PeterDuniho , I'll look into doing it that way

Comment: @RufusL oops :D Fixed.

Comment: I really don't understand what do you want to achieve. If you want to group you can just use GroupBy method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by grouping the shift events by employees:

```
var employeeShifts = _shiftEvents.GroupBy(item => item.EmpId);
```

Then iterate on them to create shifts. Create the first shift with the first shift event. If the next shift event starts when the last one ended, update the end date of the shift. If there is a gap, add the shift to a list and start a new shift with the current one.

Here's the whole solution. It got a little messy because you keep time info as string.

```
var employeeShifts = _shiftEvents.GroupBy(item => item.EmpId);

List<Shift> shifts = new List<Shift>();
foreach (IGrouping<int, ShiftEvent> employeeShift in employeeShifts)
{
    var orderedShiftEvents = employeeShift.Select(item => new { ShiftEvent = item, Interval = item.GetShiftInterval() })
                                          .OrderBy(item => item.Interval.Item1);

    Shift currentShift = null;
    foreach (var shiftEvent in orderedShiftEvents)
    {
        if (currentShift == null)
        {
            currentShift = shiftEvent.ShiftEvent.StartShift(shiftEvent.Interval);
            continue;
        }

        if (currentShift.EndOfShiftDate == shiftEvent.Interval.Item1)
        {
            currentShift.EndOfShiftDate = shiftEvent.Interval.Item2;
            currentShift.ShiftEvents.Add(shiftEvent.ShiftEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            shifts.Add(currentShift);
            currentShift = shiftEvent.ShiftEvent.StartShift(shiftEvent.Interval);
        }
    }
    shifts.Add(currentShift);
}
```

Extension methods I had to use:

```
public static class ShiftEventExtensions
{
    public static Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> GetShiftInterval(this ShiftEvent shiftEvent)
    {
        return new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(ParseDateTime(shiftEvent.StartDate, shiftEvent.StartTime), ParseDateTime(shiftEvent.EndDate, shiftEvent.EndTime));
    }

    private static DateTime ParseDateTime(string date, string time)
    {
        string text = string.Concat(date, " ", time);
        DateTime result;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(text, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid DateTime", text);
    }

    public static Shift StartShift(this ShiftEvent shiftEvent, Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> interval)
    {
        return new Shift
        {
            EmployeeId = shiftEvent.EmpId,
            StartOfShiftDate = interval.Item1,
            EndOfShiftDate = interval.Item2,
            ShiftEvents = new List<ShiftEvent> { shiftEvent }
        };
    }
}
```

I ignored `StartOfShitTime` & `EndOfShiftTime` properties in `Shift` class because `StartOfShiftDate` & `EndOfShiftDate` is enough to store time info.

This solution also assumes that there is no overlap in shift event times.